# How to configure multiple subdomain with SSL in Apache?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, wildcard, virtualhost

Configuration:

- Debian
- Apache2
- Wildcard SSL for: *.example.com
- subdomain: a.example.com, b.example.com.
- 1 dedicated server
- Websites are in NodeJS (ProxyPass...)

For now, i'm able to get a.example.com to work.
But how i can make a.example.com AND b.example.com working on the same server ?

```
/etc/apache2/site-enable/a.example.com.conf
<VirtualHost  *:80>
  ServerName a.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://a.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost  *:80>
  ServerName www.a.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://a.example.com
</VirtualHost>
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName a.example.com
 ServerAlias www.a.example.com

 ProxyRequests off
 LimitRequestLine  150000
 LimitRequestFieldSize 150000
 <Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 <Location />
  ProxyPass http://localhost:4949/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4949/
 </Location>

 SSLEngine on
 SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
 SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL

 SSLCertificateFile   /etc/ssl/2__.example.fr.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile  /root/XXXXXX.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile    /etc/ssl/1_root_bundle.crt 
</VirtualHost>
```

UPDATE ---
If i try this:

```
/etc/apache2/site-enable/b.example.com.conf
<VirtualHost  *:80>
ServerName b.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://b.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost  *:80>
ServerName www.b.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://b.example.com
/VirtualHost>

Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName b.example.com
 ServerAlias www.b.example.com

 ProxyRequests off
 LimitRequestLine  150000
 LimitRequestFieldSize 150000
 <Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 <Location />
  ProxyPass http://localhost:6949/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:6949/
 </Location>

 SSLEngine on
 SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
 SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL

 SSLCertificateFile   /etc/ssl/2__.example.fr.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile  /root/XXXXXX.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile    /etc/ssl/1_root_bundle.crt 
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm getting this

```
[....] Restarting web server: apache2[Thu Jul 21 14:58:01 2016] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Jul 21 14:58:01 2016] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
[Thu Jul 21 14:58:01 2016] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting [Thu Jul 21 14:58:02 2016] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Jul 21 14:58:02 2016] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
[Thu Jul 21 14:58:02 2016] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
```

--- UPDATE

I removed Listen 443 on b.exemple.com.conf

But now, i have this:

```
a.example.com ---> b.example.com
b.example.com ---> b.example.com
```

The problem is that when i try to access to a, i'm redirected to b

What i'm doing wrong ?

```
/etc/apache2/site-enable/b.example.com.conf
<VirtualHost  *:80>
ServerName b.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://b.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost  *:80>
ServerName www.b.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://b.example.com
/VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName b.example.com
 ServerAlias www.b.example.com

 ProxyRequests off
 LimitRequestLine  150000
 LimitRequestFieldSize 150000
 <Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 <Location />
  ProxyPass http://localhost:6949/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:6949/
 </Location>

 SSLEngine on
 SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
 SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL

 SSLCertificateFile   /etc/ssl/2__.example.fr.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile  /root/XXXXXX.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile    /etc/ssl/1_root_bundle.crt 
</VirtualHost>
```

**-- UPDATE FOUND A SOLUTION : )**

I finally found a solution for my problem, thank you for your help !

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost *:443    
</IfModule>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.fr
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/404"

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL

  SSLCertificateFile   /etc/ssl/2__.example.fr.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile  /root/XXXXX.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile    /etc/ssl/1_root_bundle.crt 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName www.example.fr
    Redirect permanent / https://a.example.fr
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName a.example.fr
    Redirect permanent / https://a.example.fr
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin admin@admin.fr
  ServerName a.example.fr

  ProxyRequests off
  LimitRequestLine  150000
  LimitRequestFieldSize 150000
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:4949/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4949/
  </Location>

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL

  SSLCertificateFile   /etc/ssl/2__.example.fr.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile  /root/serveurA.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile    /etc/ssl/1_root_bundle.crt 

</VirtualHost>





<VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName b.example.fr
    Redirect permanent / https://b.example.fr
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin admin@admin.fr
  ServerName b.example.fr

  ProxyRequests off
  LimitRequestLine  150000
  LimitRequestFieldSize 150000
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:6949/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:6949/
  </Location>

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL

  SSLCertificateFile   /etc/ssl/2__.example.fr.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile  /root/serveurA.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile    /etc/ssl/1_root_bundle.crt 

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Well, you just add a second ssl host and configure the same certificate files to be used.

Comment: Please see my update :)

Comment: Looks like you use the command `Listen 443` _twice_, one time in each file?

Comment: Yes ! It's better.
But i have another problem now, please see my update.

Comment: This might be an effect caused by the fact that b.example.com might be considered the "default host" by your setup. This is a question of the order you include the configurations.

Comment: Another thing: I'd say it would make sense to define the ssl versions of www.*.example.com as separate hosts too, so that you can redirect requests to those to the "non-www" hosts, just as you do it with the http to https redirection. I cannot see any reason to keep both variants usable.

Comment: Indeed the order of the configuration change what i'm able to access.
But the problem is still here:
-  if i want a.example.com, i get a.example.com 
-  if i want b.example.com, i get a.example.com

What i m doing wrong ... ?

Answer (score 8):

Change your virtualhost code for wildcard (*.example.com) for all sub-domain, to implement this feature your SSL certificate should be a **wildcard**  which supports for multiple sub-domains

Change / add two lines in `<virtualhost>` code of apache **httpd.conf** or **ssl.conf** file

```
 ServerName www.example.com
 ServerAlias *.example.com
```

Examples :

```
a.example.com
b.example.com
WHATEVER_SUB-DOMAIN_TEXT.example.com
```

Comment: ServerAlias should work. Awaiting for the reply from the OP. I didn't realize how old this post is! LOL